# too much hyphenations at the edge of columns

Tags: hyphenation, justification

I am using a journal template for preparing my paper. The problem is that it creates a lot of hyphenated words at the edge of the columns in the pdf file. The following figure shows an example column:

[image]

The preamble of my document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[5p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage{mdwmath,mdwtab}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[bold,full]{complexity}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{subcaption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{paper title......}
\author{FullName}
\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
....
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
...
```

I tried using `\hyphenchar\font=-1` but it did not solve the problem. I tried using `\hyphenpenalty = 10000` or `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`; they remove the hyphenations but cause another problem: the columns are not justified and some words go over the boundary of the columns.

There should be a solution because when I am trying the template of another journal, it is good and there are not many hyphenations. Could you please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a MWE (minimal code showing your problems)? Did you try to change the wording of some sentences?

Comment: @MS-SPO I added an image. Does it help?

Comment: @Cror2014 - Not really. Please start by telling us more about the document class that's in use and how wide the text block is. If available publicly, please tell us more about the "template" (in the form of a LaTeX style file?) that you are employing. A separate thought: Assuming you're using this template because the journal has told you to do so, *why* are you concerned with the consequences in terms of the frequency of hyphenation? Is it a purely aesthetic concern, or are you worried that the legibility of your text is impaired by the plentiful presence of hyphenated words?

Comment: @Mico I added the latex codes of the preamble. The reason I am concerned is that at the end, the paper is going to be read by the reviewers and I think having a lot of hyphenations over the paper affects its legibility.

Comment: I think there should be an option that makes latex to prefer adjusting the length of spaces or letters in each line instead of hyphenating the words at the end of the line (maybe this is how the other journal's template does and so it does not have the problem); but I don't know what command to use.

Comment: Please try with `\finalhyphendemerits =1000000` and `\doublehyphendemerits=1000000`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks. I tried it and there was improvement. But I found another solution which seems even better. That is to use \hyphenpenalty = 10000 and \sloppypar together.

Comment: you could use `\sloppy` so latex prefers stretching space, but I believe you are mistaken, most readers will find over-stretched spaces far more distracting than hyphenations, which are hardly noticable while reading. (`sloppypar` is intended as an environment form, `\sloppy` is the command form, but dont add `\hyphenpenalty = 10000` at the same time as that can only make things worse in narrow columns.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point. Yes, in some lines there are long spaces which don't look good; but on the other hand, the hyphenations are way more than being unnoticed. I'll try to find some solution in between, if possible at all.

Comment: @Cror2014, if you are concerned about the content of your text, use package blindtext. It just fills your space with one or more useless words. Old trick used to check layout :) // It may already be on your system. If not: https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext?lang=en

Comment: @MS-SPO, Good to know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you needed all of that preamble to demonstrate the problem. Also some text was needed to show the problem. Maybe this example would have been sufficient where I use the package kantlipsum to generate some text in English.

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

With pdflatex this generates a document from which this is the first paragraph:

[image]

If you add a line `\usepackage{microtype}` you will instead get this paragraph with just one hyphenation, and also in the rest of the document there will be fewer of them:

[image]

Then maybe it is not a good idea to enter such technicalities in your document when the document class you should use has chosen not to do that. That will be your call.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but I don't know why the result did not change much. As I commented above, I found another solution which seems good for now.